# How to create a horizontally scrollable navigation bar, using CSS and/or JavaScript that works on phone when scrolling using finger?

Tags: javascript, css

If I have a simple list of items like:

```
<ul id='list-container'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

So let's say you are on my website on your phone and there is this list that currently only displays the first two elements and you can use your finger to scroll left in order to see the other items. How would I go about tackling this? JS or CSS way.

Without scroll bar!!

Comment: Scroll left or scroll down/up?

Comment: Well it would mainly be for mobile view. So you would use you finger to swipe from right to left because the list is horizontal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x` in css.

```
li {overflow-x: scroll;}
```

Comment: Without the scroll bar tho. It looks ugly.

Comment: @korpe, Please [take a quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+change+the+scroll+bar+css), as this isn't part of the problem; this is the only way this can be done (as far as I know).